# adding facebook plugins multiple times in same page

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a joomla module when i place that module multiple times in same page for showing different facebook plugins(comment,like,activity feed..) same following javascript sdk codes added in page multiple times -

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

It creates problems sometimes plugins not shown at all and i have to refresh page to see.is there way to add these codes one time? i can place it in a external script file but i have to change language string "en_GB" dynamically to any other language according to module setting by php code so its not possible.plz help i got no solution yet.
if i can use these dec:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

then problem solved but is this right url for plugins to work perfectly without above sdk codes?

Answer (score 0):

> i can place it in a external script file but i have to change language string "en_GB" dynamically to any other language according to module setting by php code so its not possible.

Why not just output the language identifier you need as a JavaScript variable before, and then modify the line embedding the script accordingly:

```
<script>var languageToUseForFBScript = "en_GB";</script>


// in external script, embedded after above line:
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + languageToUseForFBScript + "/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: so after i declare <script>var languageToUseForFBScript = "en_GB";</script> and then i declare following external file where sdk code resides u wrote above - <script type="text/javascript" src="../sdkcodes.js"></script> u think everything will work?? considering that these declaration will appears multiple times also per module coz i am doing by javascript

Comment: k i can add the javascript sdk codes in external js file but what about

<div id="fb-root"></div> 

which i must include for sdk to work properly? how do i do so that only one "<div id="fb-root"></div>" presents in the page as each module loads that.